# Is Random class thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, random, thread-safety

Is it valid to share one instance of the `Random` class between multiple threads? And to call `nextInt(int)` from multiple threads in particular?

Comment: Care using Random to get numbers in a multithread environment can give you bad results.Maybe it does not matter but if you are doing some simulations it is good to know.

Comment: For further readers: there is a new class with 1.7 named `java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom`.

Comment: Beware of [Contention in concurrent use of java.util.Random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313552/contention-in-concurrent-use-of-java-util-random).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It is thread safe in the sense it will still generate random numbers when used by multiple threads.

The Sun/Oracle JVM implementation uses synchronized and AtomicLong as seed to improve consistency across threads. But it doesn't appear to be guarenteed across all platforms in the documentation.

I wouldn't write your program to require such a guarantee, especially as you cannot determine the order in which `nextInt()` will be called.

Comment: A guarantee has been added in the Java 7 docs: "Instances of java.util.Random are threadsafe." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 31):

It is thread safe, although it wasn't always.

See https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6362070 for more details.

Answer (score 9):

Acording to the Java 6 documentation, [Math.random()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) guarantees it's safe for use by multiple threads. But the Random class does not. I would assume then you'll have to synchronize that yourself.

EDIT:

According to the accepted answer, though, the documentation seems to have changed since Java 7 and the Random class seems to offer that guarantee too.

Comment: Under java 1.8 (RedHat OpenJDK), the Math.random() implementation looks like this:
```java
public static double random() {
    return RandomNumberGeneratorHolder.randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble();
}
// ...
private static final class RandomNumberGeneratorHolder {
    static final Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
}
```
I can't figure out how it can be considered thread-safe while java.util.Random is not...

Comment: « According to the documentation » - not « according to what I saw in the implementation ». Implementation details could vary, I just stick to what the documentation says.
According to the accepted answer, though, the documentation seems to have changed since Java 7 and the Random class seems to offer that guarantee too.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, Random is thread safe. the `nextInt()` method calls the protected `next(int)` method which uses `AtomicLong seed, nextseed` (atomic long) to generate a next seed. [`AtomicLong`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) is used for thread-safety upon seed generation.

Answer (score 6):

As said, it is thread save, but it may be wise to use `java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom` according to [this article](http://java-performance.info/java-util-random-java-util-concurrent-threadlocalrandom-multithreaded-environments/) (link dead). ThreadLocalRandom is also a subclass of Random, so it is backwards compatible.

> The article linked compared profiling results of the different Random
>   classes: `java.util.Random`, `java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom`
>   and `java.lang.ThreadLocal<java.util.Random>`. The results showed,
>   that the usage of ThreadLocalRandom is most performant, followed by
>   ThreadLocal and worst performing Random itself.

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason multiple threads can't all use the same Random.  However, since the class is not explicitly thread-safe and maintains a sequence of pseudo-random numbers via the seed.  Multiple threads may end up with the same random number.  It would be better to create multiple Randoms for each thread and seed them differently.

**EDIT**: I've just noticed that the Sun implementation uses AtomicLong so i guess that is Thread-safe (as also noted by Peter Lawrey (+1)).

**EDIT2**: OpenJDK also uses AtomicLong for the seed.  As others have said though it's still not good to rely on this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I dealt with the problem without assuming that Random uses atomic variables. It can still randomly collide if `currentTime * thread id` is equal some time in the future, but that's rare enough for my needs. To truly avoid the possibility of collisions, you could have each request wait for a unique clock timestamp.

```
/**
 * Thread-specific random number generators. Each is seeded with the thread
 * ID, so the sequence of pseudo-random numbers are unique between threads.
 */
private static ThreadLocal<Random> random = new ThreadLocal<Random>() {
    @Override
    protected Random initialValue() {
        return new Random(
            System.currentTimeMillis() *
            Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
};
```

Comment: Up! Q: is `(24*60*60*1000)` part significant?

Comment: Yeah, that was a dirty fix. The `(24*60*60*1000)` was so that a thread with ID `12` at `xxxxxxxxxx045` millis didn't get seeded the same as a thread `22` at `xxxxxxxxxx035` millis. However I don't have any good reason to assume that thread IDs are incremental, and there's no good reason to think I'm creating threads at more random times tomorrow than today. I simplified the alg now and updated the description to identify the shortcoming.

Answer (score 0):

The `Random` class is not set up for one instance to be used in multiple threads. Ofcourse, if you did this, likely you will increase the possibility of getting un-predictable and closer to *random* numbers. But since it is a pseudo-random generator, I cannot see why you would need to share an instance. Is there a more specific requirement?