# 2 randoms seem to give near identical result

Tags: java, android, random, probability

thanks in advance for taking time to look at my Q. and anyone with the same problem i hope we get a solution...

so basicly i have an app that spins 2 coins at the same time and displays what the result is.

This method generates the first coin...

```
    public void coinResult1(){
     ImageView coin1View = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coin1);
     Random r = new Random();
     int coin1result = r.nextInt(2);

     if (coin1result == 0){
        coin1View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.coinheads);
        coinresult1 = 0;
     }
        else if (coin1result == 1) {
            coin1View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cointails);
            coinresult1 = 1;
        }
}
```

and this is for the second coin

```
public void coinResult2(){
    ImageView coin2View = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coin2);

    Random r = new Random();
    int coin2result = r.nextInt(2);

    if (coin2result == 0){
        coin2View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.coinheads);
        coinresult2 = 0;
    }
        else if (coin2result == 1) {
            coin2View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cointails);
            coinresult2 = 1;
        }
}
```

this is linked to onclick() of button which check the results to a player selection

```
public void checkResult(){
        coinResult1();
        coinResult2();
        coinResult = coinresult1 + coinresult2;
        if (coinResult == playerSelection){
            playerWins();
            buttonsReset();
        }
        else {
            playerLost();
            buttonsReset();
        }
    }
```

Now the only problem i have is...
the results of both coins of 1000 presses are this...
HeadsHeads 54%

HeadsTails  2%

TailsTails 44%

of 1000000 spins was roughly the same percentages

when each coin result was counted seprately

COIN1 heads 53% tails 47%

COIN2 heads 48% tails 52%

Now my friend says their is something wrong with those odds....beacause HeadsTails wasnt a high enough percent, hes expecting it to be close to 33% each combination at random

the code seems to favour HeadsHeads and TailsTails or HeadsTails.....ive tried several times and keep getting a low % of HeadsTails

can anyone shead some light on whats going on....and what is causing HeadsTails to rarely come out?

hope to hear back soon

Comment: Instances of `Random` are seeded with the system time by default. If two instances happen to be created within a millisecond, they will effectively generate the same pseudo-random numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your repeated instantiation of `Random` is ruining the statistical properties of the generator.

You need to create one instance and pass that into your functions. Better still, use a field in your class.

Please refer to this question for concerns over thread safety of the `Random` class:[Is Random class thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819638/is-random-class-thread-safe). It seems to suggest that you should `synchronize` the `nextInt` calls.

Comment: Sorry, which threading issues did you refer to? According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819638/is-random-class-thread-safe Random class is thread safe...

Comment: @GermannArlington: That's very nice. I'm an old paranoid cat. Do you mind if I absorb this into my answer?

Comment: thanks for your answers they have all been great...ill changeCode and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

You should *never re-create* random number generator over and over again:

```
  public void coinResult1(){
    ImageView coin1View = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coin1);
    Random r = new Random(); // <- That's the source of errors!
    int coin1result = r.nextInt(2);
    ...
```

Instead, create random generator instance *once and for all*:

```
  // Simplest, not thread-safe amendment
  private static Random s_Gen = new Random();
  ...

  public void coinResult1(){
    ImageView coin1View = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coin1);

    int coin1result = s_Gen.nextInt(2);
    ...
```

The cause of the misbehaviour is that when you re-create Random it often re-initializes from the *same seed* (which is usually current time) and so generates the *same values*.

Answer (score 0):

You must create only one instance of Random.

```
    private Random r;

    // initialize r in onCreate or somehere else only once 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            // ...
    r = new Random();
}

public void coinResult1(){
     ImageView coin1View = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coin1);
     int coin1result = r.nextInt(2);

     if (coin1result == 0){
        coin1View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.coinheads);
        coinresult1 = 0;
     }
        else if (coin1result == 1) {
            coin1View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cointails);
            coinresult1 = 1;
        }
}

public void coinResult2(){
    ImageView coin2View = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coin2);
    int coin2result = r.nextInt(2);

    if (coin2result == 0){
        coin2View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.coinheads);
        coinresult2 = 0;
    }
        else if (coin2result == 1) {
            coin2View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cointails);
            coinresult2 = 1;
        }
}
```