# Is the random generator in Scala thread-safe

Tags: scala, random, thread-safety

I have the following code:

```
import scala.util.Random

val seq = Seq[Int](1, 2, 3)
val rand = new Random(123)
val gen = seq.par.map(_ => rand.nextInt(3))
println(gen.seq)
```

It prints out `Vector(2, 2, 2)`.

 It seems that the random generator in Scala is not thread-safe?

 Is that true? If so, how I could tackle with it on top of using different seeds for different threads.

 Also, if I use the random class in Java in Scala, will that still be thread-safe?

 **Related Question**

- [Is Random class thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5819638/11122122)

**Explanation**

 `par` refers to the `par` in `scala.collection.parallel.immutable`. But it seems that my computer doesn't require me to do that. And it runs on my computer.

Comment: `par` should be imported from `import scala.collection.parallel.immutable`. However, it seems that my computer doesn't require me to import that

Comment: Increase the number, you'll see you don't get the same result: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/1bFK9F5MSKeUzLtuKljo0A/2

Comment: @TomerShetah not really, because it doesn't answer the question if it is thread-safe or not. Which I remember this was already asked but I may be wrong.

Comment: @TomerShetah I'll mark my question as a duplicate then. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @TomerShetah The answer in that question doesn't really answer my question, i.e. are the random numbers generated in `scala.util.Random` in a multi-threads setting really random? However, the answer does point out that using a particular random seed in a parallel setting won't quite make sense though.

Comment: Right. Better using `ThreadLocalRandom` as explaind [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44190234/2359227).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Same as in Java. Let's take a look at the implementation of [`next`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java#L199), which is the random generator behind [`nextInt`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java#L391):

```
protected int next(int bits) {
    long oldseed, nextseed;
    AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
    do {
        oldseed = seed.get();
        nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
    } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
    return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

Basically we compute based on [`seed`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java#L87) the next element. In case the `seed` was already changed, it will create a new `nextseed`, until it succeeded to update the seed. Therefore it is thread safe.

From the same reason, it seems then in your scenario, it isn't. But, if we run the same without any parallelism, we'll get get same result.

```
import scala.util.{Failure, Random, Success}

val seq = Seq[Int](1, 2, 3)
val rand = new Random(123)
val gen = seq.map(_ => rand.nextInt(3))
println(gen.seq)
```

will result with:

```
List(2, 2, 2)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/1bFK9F5MSKeUzLtuKljo0A/4). This is becuase the first three "random" numbers for seed `123`, are `2, 2, 2`